# Как периодичиски запускать код в django?

Tags: django, celery

Я хочу периодичиски запускать код в django

Для этого я скачал Celery и попытался настроить его

Добавил в settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_celery_results',  
    'django_celery_beat',  
}

CELERY_TIMEZONE = "Australia/Tasmania"
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 30 * 60

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-cache'
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = 'default'
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'my_cache_table',
    }
}
```

Создал файл celery.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery

name='shop'
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', name+'.settings')
app = Celery(name)
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'every-15-seconds':{
        'task':'offers.tasks.send_email',
        'schedule':15,
        'args':('dsssew.com',)
    }
}
app.conf.timezone = 'UTC'
app.autodiscover_tasks()
@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

Создал файл tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def send_email(email):
    print(email)


@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


@shared_task
def mul(x, y):
    return x * y


@shared_task
def xsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```

Запустил все по очереди

```
python manage.py runserver
celery -A shop worker -l INFO
celery -A shop beat -l INFO
```

beat вывел мне

> celery beat v5.0.5 (singularity) is starting.
> __    -    ... __   -        _ LocalTime -> 2021-02-18 20:31:57 Configuration ->
> . broker -> amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
> . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
> . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
> . db -> celerybeat-schedule
> . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
> . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s) [2021-02-18 20:31:57,062: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting... [2021-02-18 20:31:57,216:
> INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task every-15-seconds
> (offers.tasks.send_email)

Но worker вывел следующее каждые 15 секунд

> File
> "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\cache\backends\base.py",
> line 287, in memcache_key_warnings
> if ord(char) < 33 or ord(char) == 127: TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

Я не понимаю в чем ошибка и как это исправить?

Comment: Если мне не врет память с версии 4.4.7 сломали аргумент, попробуй откатиться до 4.4.6